# Scope of mysql while loop

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble with scope using mysql while loops.

```
DECLARE vdate DATETIME DEFAULT now();
DECLARE vday int default 0;
WHILE (vday <  7) DO

    WHILE (vdate <  DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) DO

    //Here vday is always 0

    END WHILE;

//Here vday is 0 -6
SELECT vday +1 INTO vday;

END WHILE;
```

Can anyone clarify for me what the scope of a while loop is in mysql? How to I create a variable i can use inside a nested loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I missed something obvious (late friday problem :) ). I wasn't setting vdate back to now() after each loop of vday. As a result it would only get into the sub loop when vday was 0.